# How to access a folder inside of WSL remotely on another linux machine?

Tags: linux, networking, nas, windows-subsystem-for-linux, port

I have a NAS setup inside of WSL. The easy part was the server. For what ever reason Windows or Linux doesn't want to play nice with the rest of the network. I was able to get samba working inside of my NAS but this only allows me to access via the local host. I have a baremetal NAS that I would like to mount the storage on my virtual NAS but I can't figure out how to connect from outside the local host.I first tried samba as I am familiar with it as that is what i run on my bare metal NAS. I wasn't able to get it working and gave up quickly has I didn't want to fight the host OS over port forwarding a service it has already. So I switched to NFS figuring that windows won't care about a non Microsoft system. Well I set my port forwarding rules up, I allowed both 111, 2049 and the custom assigned port for NFSv3 and v4  through the firewall and that's when I hit a brick wall. Getting ZFS installed inside of WSL was easier than this.

Ports Tried

111 TCP/UDP

2049 TCP

20048 TCP/UDP(for mountd)

Commands used

`New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL2 Port Bridge NFSv3 mountd" -Direction Inbound -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 20048`

`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=20048 listenaddress=192.168.50.3 connectport=20048 connectaddress=(wsl hostname -I)`

`netstat -ano` for port listening on windows came back with only the v4 and v6 ports as listening no dups(Other than one for v4 and v6)

`rpcinfo -p` and `netstat -natp` came back with the WSL instance listening for those ports

But yet with I try telnet and showmount -e and the version for NFSv4 on my remote Linux box, I get a connection time out. Am I missing a step? I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking to set this up. I have tried wsl --shutdown and start up. I am a lost it should work yet doesn't(I did tried mirrored mode, it isn't supported in my windows build)

My question is any know how to either get NFS working or how to share a directory from inside of WSL to the rest of the network(Not to the localhost, like I said my smb service is working fine)?

UPDATE: Still haven't figured it out. I have figured it is a windows problem. I can seen the packets coming via wireshark but on the WSL virtual interface I don't see them being re-transmitted to the WSL guest